# script triggers owner case when triggerd by editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

when editor of my google-doc triggers a script, it triggers my own case together with his. how can i prevent that ?

i've tried both getActiveUser and getEffectiveUser with only difference being active triggerd only my case. there are currently 2 triggers one for me and the second one for the editor both created by the respective gmail accounts

```
function timestamp(e) {
  var count = 0
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var me = "xxx@gmail.com"
  var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM"+" HH:mm");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  console.log();
          
  if (!count){
  switch (userName){
    case "xxx@gmail.com":
      if (userName == me){
      body.editAsText().replaceText(">Xxx<.*$", ">Xxx< " + date);
      count = 1;
      break;
      }
    case "zzz@gmail.com":
      body.editAsText().replaceText(">Zzz<.*$", ">Zzz< " + date);
      count = 1;
      break;       
}
}
}
```

the output should be a timestamp of date and time for the user that opened the document

## console 1

```
{
 insertId: "mh4nwqe6ptif"  
 
labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/deployment_id: "AKfycbwfuWqQks2U7sKVzpX26w8lL-hm0CciOGeZ4EmtOUUi"   
  script.googleapis.com/process_id: "EAEA1GOyI3tGd4a3vorh4JNBVOHgi6RgYtgFwrZD0nvmTX_Cf0-bmsPRXgqyH6DUJSet4rxj4CCOdWLDY1NjQG1qFzsVDoB9LatI74BPQ4_8R6K1Ek6cBBXr0JyBbWMXTtPbPe_Ne4mneJWnF3oSuDEtiOv3XYBHwWJ0mKQ"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key: "MWWPE_X-NNcz9aBsDbXTBen9WCo1QLwkg"   
  script.googleapis.com/user_key: "ABkUwjbdkw+qwq/LIW606KMmYd6VVd6glH8f8PVSWy8MdK8XykhyjpFux1uTehrMsXoQJEjH8Uv8"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project-id-9053084063274654670/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-03-26T20:12:34.358323783Z"  
 
resource: {
  
labels: {
   function_name: "timestamp"    
   invocation_type: "event"    
   project_id: "project-id-9053084063274654670"    
  }
  type: "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 textPayload: "The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity."  
 timestamp: "2019-03-26T20:12:34.114Z"  
}
```

## console 2

```
 {
 insertId: "pszlqvei0ldj"  
 
labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/deployment_id: "AKfycbwfuWqQks2U7sKVzpX26w8lL-hm0CciOGeZ4EmtOUUi"   
  script.googleapis.com/process_id: "EAEA1GOyS_38lVqx6GOormX6vTH7wk4L_iK_koMbvlaUgunXHMST8CqgrmFYGcVn7suDHZf1egvGGL2XGqmmXgKqxN1IXlyBoMEt3prWsNpZnMTok5BGvUat_-KTnmv471C5-l3ATXFXQvvEEzkGJTPW7fBFLE71JBtvex1XOgd0"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key: "MWWPE_X-NNcz9aBsDbXTBen9WCo1QLwkg"   
  script.googleapis.com/user_key: "ABkUwjbdkw+qwq/LIW606KMmYd6VVd6glH8f8PVSWy8MdK8XykhyjpFux1uTehrMsXoQJEjH8Uv8"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project-id-9053084063274654670/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-03-26T20:12:33.950683014Z"  
 
resource: {
  
labels: {
   function_name: "timestamp"    
   invocation_type: "event"    
   project_id: "project-id-9053084063274654670"    
  }
  type: "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity: "DEBUG"  
 textPayload: ""  
 timestamp: "2019-03-26T20:12:33.801Z"  
}
```

## separated_code

```
function Xxx(e) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM"+" HH:mm");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  if (userName == 'Xxx@gmail.com' ) {
    body.editAsText().replaceText(">Xxx<.*$", ">Xxx< " + date);
  }
}
```

^^^repeated for all other 6 users

Comment: How did you deploy the script?

Comment: i tried making a web app and running the current version of the "web app"

Comment: at first i treid to run it as a pure script but it didn't get through to the other users so i've tried second best option i found.

Comment: Try [adding](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` to scopes and re-install the trigger.

Comment: well after all the googling i've made i arrived at the conclusion that to be able to run the script i wrote for other users i would have to deploy the script as a web app. and allow the people editing the doc to add their own triggers for the said script/app. TheMaster --> i've done the tringer onOpen as you don't need to edit the file to start the trigger. i've just needed a variable token to know when the editor had last seen the Doc. and the doGet(e) implementation was after i've recieved error on triggers to run the "app"

Comment: TheMaster i've tried redeploying the solution after adding the scopes to the json. the app works fine on my account without the trigger, but on a second user it won't run without the trigger and with trigger it still updates both of our times, i've redeployed and removed/addaed triggers

Comment: 1. You don't need a web-app/deploy. The other user needs to set up a installable trigger (Try renaming the function to something else too)2.Try `getActiveUser()` instead and use `console.log()` and provide logs here.

Comment: Any use of a simple "open" trigger should check authorization state / authmode in the event object. If those words are foreign or incomprehensible, you need to review the official Apps Script documentation on triggers. An internet search should get you where you need to be.

Comment: I've disabled the web app, reneamed the function onOpen to timestamp and i'm currently running 2 installable triggers on owner and editors accounts (both are triggerd onOpen). from the console. log i get 2 different outputs repeated 6 times , 4 for "The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity." and 2 for debug

Comment: To be clear, both owner and editor has accepted profile permission and see email permissions(The pop up that pops up, when you set up the trigger)?

Comment: If there are only two people, Easy way is to set up two functions> One function installed for the owner and other installed for the editor. No need to check for anything. Though both functions will run onopen made by owner/editor, `getActiveUser()` will not return anything for owner open trigger in a editor function and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, both profiles have the trigger set up the same way with borh accepting the extra security, and its not only 2 people, curently its around 6 but i didnt want to include repeated part of the code

Comment: i'v tried separating the script into multiple separate script files with each individual user running his own script, the result is that once one of the users that added the script opens the doc all the other people get refreshed as well (adding the separate code)

Comment: After some heavy testing, I believe this is impossible through the Session.getActiveUser(), if you're a individual and don't have a gsuite domain.  It may however be possible to get a anonymous temporary userkey and use it instead if you like. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTemporaryActiveUserKey()

Comment: in the end, i've decided that making it automatic was impossible as after you said, the test proved me wrong but i managed to get a solution through creating an dropdown add-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as TheMaster suggested i think i can't manage to get the fully automated solution i wished for, but i've found a workaround

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('timestamp' , 'Dontrun')
      .addToUi();
}

function Dontrun(e) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM"+" HH:mm");
  var body = doc.getBody();

  switch (userName){
    case "xxx@gmail.com":
      body.editAsText().replaceText(">Xxx<.*$", ">Xxx< " + date);
      break;
    case "zzz@gmail.com":
      body.editAsText().replaceText(">Zzz<.*$", ">Zzz< " + date);
      break;       
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting... So, if the user himself clicks the menu item, `activeUser` returns the email. Is that right?

Comment: i think so, i'm using it for 3rd day today and it works like a charm also expandable and reacts to the users email